Hartree Fock STO-3G H2 converging to the wrong solution
I have recently written a Hartree-Fock program using STO-3G. I have been testing it on the H2 molecule, but I am running into issues involving converging to the correct energy.
My overlap matrix, core hamiltonian, and two electron integrals are correct. I am using $H_{core}$ as an initial guess to the Fock matrix $F$, and after obtaining a new density matrix $P$ and a new $F$ and computing the energy, I get the correct value of $-1.831$ Ha (per Szabo & Ostlund). After this first iteration, I also get the correct orbital energies:
6.7026776062e-01    0.0000000000e+00
0.0000000000e+00   -5.7820297686e-01

and the correct coefficient matrix, up to some digits:
5.4893404119e-01   -1.2114640715e+00
5.4893403972e-01    1.2114640744e+00

However, after the second iteration, the total energy becomes $-0.2537$ Ha. The orbital energies become
2.2189303779e-01    0.0000000000e+00
0.0000000000e+00   -1.0692699649e-01

and the coefficient matrix becomes
-1.2114640647e+00    5.4893405620e-01
1.2114640772e+00    5.4893403353e-01

These values are consistent for the next few iterations and it converges very closely to these values. What is interesting to note is that the coefficient matrices seem to be the same up to permutation of the rows and a negative sign (up to some digits).
Is there something which might be causing my program to converge to the wrong values? My SCF iterations as of now proceed simply by using the old density matrix as a guess for the new one.
I should also mention that after testing on HeH+, the program converges after a few steps to the correct solution. Is there some inherent instability in the calculation on H2? It seems strange that what should be a simpler case presents this issue.
Edit: Another detail which may be significant is that I have even tried using the correct density matrix as the initial guess and it still converges to the same wrong solution as above.

Can't really say much from the above. But as a complete guess I note you list the evals, unusually, in decreasing order. Are you sure when generating the density matrix you are using the correct orbitals?

@IanBush This is an interesting point. I cannot recall where, but I now remember reading that the orbital energies should be ordered from lowest to highest. Should I simply reorder the energies (and the corresponding columns of the coefficient matrix) to be lowest to highest? I will try this and return if it works.

The ordering in a sense doesn't matter - you should just use the evecs corresponding to the lowest Ne/2 evals when constructing the density matrix (at least for simple cases like this), where Ne is the number of electrons. But yes, ordering the evecs in order of increasing evals and then using the lowest is probably the simplest way to achieve this. What software are you using to diagonalise the matrix?

@IanBush It was exactly this! I went ahead and ordered the columns of the orbital coefficient matrix such that the lowest energy orbital was in the first column, and the program works. Thank you so much!

IanBush was correct in identifying that my program simply was not using the correct orbitals to construct the next density matrix. To ensure that the correct orbitals were used in each iteration, I simply ordered the columns of my coefficient matrix $C$ such that the orbital with the lowest orbital energy was listed first (ascending order) before using it to begin the next iteration.
